# Is it appropriate for Granny to say "**honey**" to Grandson?

Tags: word-usage

Picture this, a granny prepares a dinner for her grandson.

> Grandson: thank you, granny.

Granny pats the child on the head and says

> Granny: That's OK my **honey**.

In this kind of scenario, is it appropriate for Granny to say "**honey**"?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the dictionary definitions, 'honey' is described in one as "*an affectionate way to address a person*", and another says it is synonymous with "*darling*". There is nothing to say it is limited to partners in a romantic relationship, although I think that is how it most commonly used, especially in American English (in British English, it is something of a cliche, and we are more likely to say "darling" or "love").

However, this might vary from culture to culture, and although I am not used to hearing it regularly in British English, having been exposed to a variety of English-speaking cultures through books, television and movies, it sounds perfectly natural to me for a grandparent to say it to a grandchild.